# How can I place the search, login and registration buttons in the header on the right side of menu?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, menu

So this is the menu, but I want the circled three buttons to be on the right side...How can I do this?
I am using Angular material.

[image: menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Angular Material toolbar, follow the [official documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/overview)

From the doc:

> The toolbar does not perform any positioning of its content. This gives the user full power to position the content as it suits their application.

```
<mat-toolbar-row>
  <span>Second Line</span>
  <span class="example-spacer"></span>
  <mat-icon class="example-icon" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example user verified icon">verified_user</mat-icon>
</mat-toolbar-row>
```

> A common pattern is to position a title on the left with some actions
> on the right. This can be easily accomplished with display: flex:

```
.example-spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Follow the documentation and you'll have the three buttons on the right side

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Angular Material, but I think you can use this:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" style="display : flex , justify-content :"space-between">
   <any Element(Tag)></any Element(Tag)>
   <any Element(Tag)></any Element(Tag)>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a spacer that act like a place holder for the right part position.

```
<span class="example-spacer"></span>
```

you need also to add its css class, for example

```
.example-spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

You can find similar implementations in the official website for angular materials.
https://v6.material.angular.io/components/toolbar/examples